# How to only throw a Status code when unauthorized in MVC 5 - no redirect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

So I created a custom authorization filter in MVC 5 following an answer given on stackoverflow. It looks like this:

```
public class AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/AccessDenied");
        }
    }
}
```

Since I don't want to actually redirect the user to a page at all but just want to show a bootstrap alert, I customized the code like this:

```
public class AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
    }
}
```

and I use this javascript code:

```
$('#settingsIndex').on('click', function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Settings/Index',
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "/Settings/Index";
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function () {
                $('#loginAlert').show();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

This does work to a point. When I click on the link with the specified Id the alert will show but nevertheless MVC still redirects me to the login page (when only using the filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200; code piece), when adding my custom redirect it redirects me to my custom page.

I would rather have it not redirect the user at all and just show the bootstrap alert.

I tried adding this piece of code also:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
```

That doesn't work either. How can I stop MVC from redirecting and only show the alert?

Comment: every successed request will redirect to `"/Settings/Index"` is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Elmer, correct. But any failed/unauthorized request should not redirect the user at all but show the alert....

Comment: your filter is only setting the response code to 200, which means `success` that's why you keep being redirect. Try change to 200 to 401. in any case the best option is to throw an exception and show you alert on the `error` function of the ajax call.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. When changing the response to 401 it doesn't even show the alert anymore - only redirects :/

Comment: why not just throw an exception instead of change the `statusCode`? then you show you alert on the `error` function of the ajax call.

Comment: Damn. I'm lost now Elmer. I tried throwing an exception which kind of worked. I could show the alert on the error function but now even if the user is supposed to have access, I get the error, too.
I need to throw the exception in the AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute class or am I wrong?
And would I be checking for this? filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult or something else? I don't get it - still pretty new to programming tho :|

Comment: it seems you `Result` is always `HttpUnauthorizedResult` which means you need to understand why your code giving you this. If you post more details about the code you're using it will be easier to help you. Maybe you need to change your check for `!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as you´re new, I suggest you read a little bit more about how to use filters/custom filters and the authentication using MVC. Just copying code wihtout understanding it won't help you.